# Can anyone convert this to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript to make use of a modal overlay.  Can this be converted to jQuery?

```
  function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
```

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. This is a site for asking questions.

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to convert a perfectly working fragment of JavaScript into jQuery? (*edit*: You're missing a `var`)

Comment: Well the question was supposed to be is it possible and if so how.  Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function overlay() {
    var el = $("#overlay");
    el.css("visibility",((el.css("visibility") == "visible")?"Hidden":"visible"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function overlay() {
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    if (overlay.css('visibility')==='hidden'){
        overlay.css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        overlay.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/css/ for details of the css() function.

Comment: Not really equivalent. Toggle will alter the element's `display` property, while OP is switching the element's `visibility`.

Comment: Changed it based on what I learned from you.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @MikeHogan: Remove that text from the edit and instead explain what you did. Downvotes can be reverted.

Comment: @Zeta, wrote out my learning experience.

Comment: @MikeHogan: That's nice, but don't forget, after all, an answer should be, well, an answer. It's best to keep focused on the topic itself. If you ask a question, you're not really interested in some ramble how someone found the correct solution, are you? You want an answer and maybe some details about it (for example a link to the reference of `.css`, hint hint). Remember this for future answers :).

Comment: @Zeta, fair enough :) I thought writing out my learning experience was what you were suggesting when you said "explain what you did".  Have corrected the answer and learned plenty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function overlay() {
  el = $("#overlay");
  if(el.css('visibility')=='hidden') {
    el.css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    el.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `var` statement, now you're introducing an unwanted global.

Comment: There was no var statement in his code, so I assumed he wanted el to be global.  I agree it should be local, but why muddy the water of this question with discussion about global vs. local variables?

Comment: It's also about good coding practices. If someone has an SQL injection vulnerability in their code, I'll not refrain from telling them so.

Comment: Sure - feel free to take it up with the original asker, as that aspect of the code is unchanged from their original snippet.

Comment: I'm going to stop responding as I don't feel this discussion is constructive.  If you have tangential problems with the original code posted, please make them to the person who originally posted the code.